# Jquery and CSS animation not working in ANDROID Webview application

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, webview

I am trying to make a Webview for my website. But i have one problem with jquery code.

This is my **[DEMO](http://www.ecowebtr.com)** site. In this demo site you can see when you click the image then detail div will open with animation.

But that detail is not open when i click the image.

> Note: I am a new in Android

Here is my application code for Webview:

```
package ecowebtr.ecowebtr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private CustomWebViewClient webViewClient;
    private String Url = "http://www.ecowebtr.com/";
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

        webViewClient = new CustomWebViewClient();

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); 
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient); 
        webView.loadUrl(Url);


    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) { 
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            if(!mProgressDialog.isShowing())
            {
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            if(mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,String description, String failingUrl) {


        }
    }
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer. Just want to say, that's really nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code to solve:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);

WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    settings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + this.getPackageName() + "/databases/");
}
```